# Are there any good sites for consolidating travel plans into a single itinerary?

Tags: webapp-rec

I just got back from an overseas holiday for a month. I booked everything online including flights, other transport, and accommodation.

Each website gives you your own receipt (usually in an email) but it's difficult to get an overall picture of the holiday without organizing it yourself in a spreadsheet.

**Are there any web apps that are useful for organizing all of this travel information into a single itinerary?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Tripit.com](http://www.tripit.com/) works for me - I haven't tried the Pro version, but the free version does quite nicely.

The UI couldn't be simpler - you simply forward your confirmation emails to plans@tripit.com, and they parse the results & present them to you.  I've used it with a number of different airlines, car reservations, and hotel reservations, and never had a problem with it.

(I have no association with the company, just a satisfied customer)

Comment: Wow, if that works as advertised, it looks awesome...

Comment: Tripit iPhone app is great too.

Comment: Just as a follow up, I've signed up to this and it's *awesome*. Give it a go if you stumble across this question...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [TripIt](http://www.tripit.com) and [TripCase](http://www.tripcase.com). Both are good although I prefer the TripCase interface. Both have iPhone apps, and probably apps for other smartphones. I've just got back from a trip involving Australia, the US and Mexico, and TripCase worked seamlessly with updating airflight times and hotel reservations.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Kayak Trips.  It's still a work in progress, but it handles flights, hotels and car reservations really well.  You can also add your own events, and send the itenerary to other people.