# What are the best travel web apps/sites?

Tags: webapp-rec

The "web revolutionized the travel" industry, enabling "people to be their own travel agents". With the improvements in mapping technologies and the ability to share knowledge, it has never been easier to find the deals you need regarding the places you want to see.

Please list out the websites/web-apps you use most of the time.

I'm not looking for consolidating travel plans.

[Are there any good sites for consolidating travel plans into a single itinerary?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3721/are-there-any-good-sites-for-consolidating-travel-plans-into-a-single-itinerary)

Comment: code blocks are used for code and queries (sometimes to represent a button) I remove the code blocks you used. If you want you can use italics (asterisk closure)

Comment: @phwd np at  all :)

Comment: Obviously [Travel-SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.tripadvisor.com/

I find [Trip Advisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/) very handy for getting reviews of hotels.

Comment: My only problem with Trip Advisor is that ads and popups can be annoying. Aside from that, its a great site with lots of information and reviews.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Everlater](http://everlater.com), a free travel blog with maps and diaries.

Answer (score 2):

- [Couchsurfing](http://www.couchsurfing.org/) is a great way to find free places to stay, good people, and points of interest from locals.  It requires an investment in the community, but if you are gonna do a lot of wandering it is a must.
- I just tried using [Atlas Obscura](http://atlasobscura.com/) for a trip to Seattle and its the reason that we found our way to the [freemont troll](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fremont_Troll), which was awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I actually find [Booking.com](http://www.booking.com) to be awesome, not just for booking hotels.  The reviews and photos are pretty informative.

Answer (score 1):

[Tripsay](http://www.tripsay.com/) is an interesting app for discovering new travel ideas.

Answer (score 1):

you might consider using the great lonely planet

Comment: I thought you were kidding, but it happens to be travel website :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Hipmunk](http://hipmunk.com) for searching for flights..  It just launched last week.  It has a pretty cool interface for showing you the results of your search.

Comment: Web page under construction?

Comment: @pramodc84: Whoops I put the wrong url!!

Comment: Haha, I like "sort by agony"

Comment: No good for Europe yet (no EasyJet, no RyanAir). But it will be good when they get those in.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another (new) app that seems really interesting - [Wanderfly](http://www.wanderfly.com/)

Wanderfly is a travel recommendation engine that helps people discover where they can go based on their budgets and interests. More info from Mashable - http://mashable.com/2010/10/21/wanderfly/

Answer (score 0):

[**Costco Travel**](http://www.costcotravel.com/) sells vacation destinations, hotels, resorts, cruise lines, rental car companies, theme-park vacations, escorted vacations.