# Web app for hotel deals and vacancy data?

Tags: webapp-rec

What's a good web app for finding hotel deals and includes real time vacancy data about the hotels? What about one with an API? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: That would be nice for planning a road trip (on the road)!

Comment: Similar, maybe more general: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/what-are-the-best-travel-web-apps-sites.  I'd still answer [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/) for this. API is partner only, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best hotel deals so far I've found on [hotwire.com](http://hotwire.com). They have an [API](http://developer.hotwire.com/docs) as well. We did use them to plan a road trip while on the road :). I don't believe they offer vacancy data though (of course, this being hotwire, you won't know what hotel you're booking until you've booked it - but no disappointments yet).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [m.hotels.com](http://m.hotels.com), they've got a pretty well done mobile site, and they are pretty good for prices, bookings and information.